# What is the distribution of phone users vs question score?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm frequently visiting the physics Stack Exchange site via my phone and sometimes I ask a question too.

While by design the phone is not optimal for asking a question as compared to a laptop or PC. I'm curious, do we have data for the number of phone users vs. question score (and question closing) obtained? And if the distribution is not satisfactory, maybe we can discuss some policy over phone users?

Answer (score 6):

I know that Stack Exchange, like any large website, keeps statistics about how many of its users use various browser versions, which includes some information about operating system and can be used to distinguish phone users from tablet users from desktop users. But
I suspect that accumulated statistics about *which* users use *which* operating systems would run into hairy privacy territory. There is certainly nothing like "browser type" in the public Data Explorer.

For one datum, I access the site both ways.  I seem to make shorter paragraphs when I'm writing on a phone than I do when I'm writing on a desktop. Occasionally, I'll revisit a phone-written answer from a desktop computer, and think "why did I make all these short little paragraphs?"